# Error when adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model from Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework, odp.net

I am trying to create an EF context from an Oracle database in .NET 4.

I installed Oracle Developer Tools for VS extension, I also installed `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` and Entity Framework Nuget packages:

```
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net462" />
 <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="21.9.0" targetFramework="net462" />
 <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="21.9.0" targetFramework="net462"/>
```

My scenario is like this:

- Right click project then add new item and choose ADO.NET Entity Data Model
- Choose EF Designer From Database Click new Connection (Data Source=Oracle Database and Data Provider=ODP.NET managed driver).
- In connection type advance mode I am entering data source, username and password. Test connection is success - everything is ok
- But when I pressing OK button, I am getting this error. I can't understand why ODT extension is using the GAC. The extension already includes `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dll`. I can't update the GAC because I don't have the admin role. Also I don't want to use GAC at design time and runtime.

[image: this]